# Can TypeScript compile included references in each js file?

Tags: typescript

Having trawled https://stackoverflow.com and https://www.typescriptlang.org/ I have reached a dead end.

I am using Typescript to write js for a clientAPI which points to a single web resource. For coding, I wanted to reference separate ts files to reuse code. I need each js file that compiles to contain the helper functions and not reference another file. The reference is just for source but the functions need to be combined instead of emitted.

My project structure looks something like this:

- tsconfig.json
- SRC

  - resource1.ts (using helper)
  - resource2.ts (using helper)
- HELPER

  - helper.ts
- DIST

  - resource1.js (helper function included)
  - resource2.js (helper function included)

Is this possible for typescript? I have looked at modules, references and compiler flags but haven't manage to make sense of anything.

The closest I have come is "outFile" in the compiler options. This merges the code into a single output which is partly what I want, but it merges all code. Resource1.js and Resource2.js still want to be separate files.

I thought adding tsconfig.json to define each outFile might do it.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "outFile": "./Dist/WebResources/Resource1/Resource1.js"
  }
}
```

I'm trying something like this but although the outFiles are emitting each js in the correct location, the helper code isn't included again:

- tsconfig.json
- SRC

  - WEBRESOURCES

    - RESOURCE1

      - resource1.ts (using helper)
      - tsconfig.json
    - RESOURCE2

      - resource2.ts (using helper)
      - tsconfig.json
- HELPER

  - helper.ts
- DIST

  - WEBRESOURCES

    - RESOURCE1

      - resource1.js (using helper)
    - RESOURCE2

      - resource2.js (using helper)

Now it is saying

```
SRC/WEBRESOURCES/RESOURCE*/DIST/WEBRESOURCES/RESOURCE*/resource*.d.ts not found.
```

It is adding the outfile to the source path but should be looking for

```
DIST/WEBRESOURCES/RESOURCE*/resource*.d.ts
```

I'm dangerously close to copy/pasting the required helper functions into each file.